# How to change the ActiveX settings for Internet Explorer on Win8.1 using registry entries?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8.1, activex

Using the details given in the KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569, I could easily change AciveX settings for IE by editing the following 4 registry entries for on Win7-IE10.

1. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2201
2. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1001
3. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1200
4. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1405

But on Win8.1 IE11, I don't see above 4(2201, 1001, 1200, 1405) registry entries for ActveX under Zones section.
Is there any alternative on Win8.1 to change Internet Explorer ActiveX setting using registry?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution! We can manually add the following missing registry entries in Win8.1.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2201
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1001
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1200
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1405
```

After adding these entries, we can modify the activex setting for IE on Win8.1, by editing the these entries accordingly.
It works awesomely.